# How to give user the browser's native auth dialog from javascript without refreshing the whole page?

Tags: javascript, http-authentication

I really like the browser's native auth dialog. Not something written in html form, but the dialog the browser shows for "WWW-Authenticate: Digest" header etc. Now I want to give user this dialog when a user clicks a certain html button, and handle the response from server in a javascript callback without refreshing the whole page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to show something without refreshing the whole HTML page. The technique is called **AJAX** (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML). This is a JavaScript technique which allows us to send data to server and get the result from the server without refreshing the whole HTML page.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

The upper three links describes the AJAX technique.

The second technique is .load() which loads html data into selected container(div, selector, etc.).You can load the AJAX which shows the dialog box when user clicks on a button.

I hope you will get some help from my answer.